# Find max and min date from an array of date strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I have an array of objects as follows

```
data = [
 {
  mas_name: (...),
  mas_plan_end: (...) // 'YYYY-MM-DD' eg: '2021-03-19'
  mas_plan_start: (...) // 'YYYY-MM-DD' eg: '2021-03-19'
  ...
 },
 {
  mas_name: (...),
  mas_plan_end: (...) 
  mas_plan_start: (...)
  ...
 }
]
```

In the above array, some of the objects might even contain mas_plan_start as null..
I need to get the minimum and maximum values of mas_plan_start from this array.
I tried using moments in the following manner

```
const max = moment.max(children.map((o) =>
          o.mas_plan_start ? o.mas_plan_start : moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        )) ;

const min = moment.min(children.map((o) =>
          o.mas_plan_start ? o.mas_plan_start : moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
        )) ;
```

But it threw me this error
[image]

How can I fix this, ...or is there any way to do this without using moments.

Solution:

```
const max_date = moment.max(data.filter((o) =>
          o.mas_plan_end !== null
        ).map((date) =>
        moment(date.mas_plan_end, 'YYYY-MM-DD') // converting to moment instance so that .max command will work
        ));
      parent.mas_plan_end = max_date._i; // to get the date String back from the moment instance
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: _"without using moments"_ - Get all date strings and sort them. With the given format the first element will be _min_ and the last _max_

Comment: Ya if I sort it in ascending..the first element will be min and last elem will be max...but how will I perform this sort on date-strings?

Comment: The same way - at least in the given format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: Could the minimum date be from the `mas_plan_end` too or just `mas_plan_start`?

Comment: no its just the mas_plan_start that ll be considered

Comment: [`moment.min()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/min/): _"Returns the minimum (most distant past) of the given **moment instances**."_ (the same for `.max()`) - You're passing an array of strings.

Comment: the same command is what I used but I got that error

Comment: the array of strings Iam passing...is that right or wrong?

Comment: I've posted the relevant part of the documentation (+ a link), and even highlighted the important part. A **moment instance** is not a string.

Comment: I see... now I got it. Thanks a lot that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used `moment.js` before but from your code, I figure this is how it's used to format dates

```
const max = moment(data.map(obj => new Date(obj.mas_plan_end ?? '')).reduce((a, b) => b > a ? b : a)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
const min = moment(data.map(obj => new Date(obj.mas_plan_start ?? '')).reduce((a, b) => b < a ? b : a)).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

The `??` operator I used is called the `nullish coalescing operator` it returns the second value, if the first value is null or undefined. [Nullish Coalescing MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

Comment: This didnt work but anyways thanks for posting a solution. I have updated the solution above pls check

Comment: You are not passing the moment instance to the min and Max functions

Comment: I mapped through the data array to get the max and min dates then I found the greater and lesser dates then passed it into the moment function to format it.... Was the answer wrong?